# SQL Server db data partition grows drastically when population a bit column

Tags: sql-server, database, size

This is my first time posting here so hopefully I didn't mess anything up.

I have used an alter table to add a bit type column to an existing database, in order to know if that item is out of stock or not. When adding the new column it gets the null value so I want to update it to 0 (In stock) and in most of the databases, there were no problems. The thing is that in larger databases I found that the data partition size grows a lot (from 700 gb up to 800 gb) causing some drive space problems.

The table has about 2 billion rows, so the increase on the data partition was expected but never thought that a `bit` type column could cause an increase like that since it suppose it should consume 1 bit each (or at least from what I understand).

I'm not an database expert and I require to be sure why this happen in order to have a better understanding and be able to proceed with the changes on the remaining databases making sure this is not going to go out of control.

Comment: Are you adding the column _with a default value_? What version/edition of SQL Server? The table isn't growing by that much because you've added a bit column. The table is growing because if you've added a column and the data no longer fits on a page (e.g. a page is already full), SQL Server has to allocate a new page and move half the data there. If all your pages are full, well, you'll be allocating a lot of new pages. On newer versions (and maybe only Enterprise Edition?) it can get added such that it doesn't need to allocate all the new space up front, so it is quicker / less impact.

Comment: Some background [here](http://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/online-non-null-with-values-column-add-in-sql-server-11/) and [here](https://sqljudo.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/when-is-alter-table-just-a-meta-data-change/). If you can't take advantage of this, I would suggest trying to add the column as `NULL` and either making your code treat `NULL` as 0 or adding the constraint and updating the data in batches after the column is added.

Comment: I set the 0 as default value but on already existed data the value was set to null, that is why i update after that to set the value to 0. The SQL Server version is 2012. I will read the links you shared. Thanks!

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: Sorry, i had no idea about that. How can i do to move it??

Answer (score 0):

Bits are packed per-table into bytes, so adding one bit column to a table (if there weren't any before) will cost 1 byte per row.

Adding the second to eighth bit columns are free.

Adding the ninth, costs 1 more byte storage etc.

Comment: Having that in consideration, the size should be arround 300mb, not 100gb at it is. Anyway thanks for sharing that since it is something i didn't know so it is usefull to have in consideration from now on.